# What's a @media rule without a media type do?

Tags: css, media-queries

I inherited this and was wondering what does a media query without a "media type" do?

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
   .commentlist-item .commentlist-item {
    padding: 0 0 0 2em;
   }
}
```

Standard syntax per www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

```
  @media not|only mediatype and (expressions) {
    CSS-Code;
}
```

Comment: Where did you see the second syntax? W3C has official documentation, which don't even have anything called `mediatype` - https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: From www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp. Also at the link you gave, I see in section labeled "3. Syntax" that there is a media type.

Comment: The w3schools article you linked says "Unless you use the `not` or `only` operators, the media type is optional and the `all` type will be implied."

Comment: Note that w3schools is *not* official documentation and is generally not seen positively around here.

Comment: OK...thanks for the input.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If the media type is not explicitly given it is `all`. ~ [*W3C Media Queries*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0)

In other words, an @media rule without a media type is shorthand syntax, where  `all` is implied.

More from the spec:

> [**2. Media
>   Queries**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0)
>
> A shorthand syntax is offered for media queries that apply to all
>   media types; the keyword `all` can be left out (along with the
>   trailing `and`). I.e. if the media type is not explicitly given it is
>   `all`.
>
> EXAMPLE 5
>
> I.e. these are identical:
>
> ```
> @media all and (min-width: 500px) { ... } 
> @media (min-width: 500px) { ... }
> ```
>
> As are these:
>
> ```
> @media (orientation: portrait) { ... }
> @media all and (orientation: portrait) { ... }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> EXAMPLE 7
>
> I.e. these are equivalent:
>
> ```
> @media all { ... }
> @media { ... }
> ```
>
> *<sub>source: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0</sub>*

Comment: Note, `all and` is required if using `not`. So you cannot do `not (...)`, you have to do `not all and (...)`