# Build a media query for print and screen with min-width

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to have a stylesheet that is appropriate for print and screens of decent width.

I hope my intent is obvious when I type:

```
@media print or (screen and (min-width: 801px)) {
    Rules here
}
```

Sadly, this won’t work.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: I found a link that may provide even more information than any direct answers: https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/

Answer (score 8):

Try this (a comma seperates several independent condtions/queries):

```
@media print, screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    Rules here
}
```

Comment: Weirdly, `@media screen, print and ... ` wasn't working for me in print preview (Firefox and Chrome), but writing it as `@media print, screen and ...` does.

Comment: @turrican_34 well, with `@media screen, print and (min-width: 801px)` the width setting would only apply to the printed output (the comma separates the media queries completely)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
@media print, (min-width: 801px) {
    Rules here
}
```

That would be for OR.

Just FYI, an AND structure would look like this:

```
@media print and (min-width: 801px) {
    Rules here
}
```

Comment: The `and` and `,` can be combined too, right?
Like `@media print, screen and (min-width: 100px)`?

Comment: @BDawg yes, and I think that's the real answer for this question

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In my answer, `screen` is implied, but you can be more specific if you want. See my answer here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35658627/3597276

Answer (score 3):

```css
@media print, screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    .intro_text{
        border: solid 1px blue;
     }
}
```

works on a Mac (Safari, Chrome and Firefox.) Note the comma and fewer parentheses per:

> [2.1 Combining Media Queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mq-list)
>
> "Several media queries can be combined into a comma-separated media query list."

I would think, given:

> [2.4. Media Features](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mq-features)
>
> Media features are always wrapped in parentheses and combined with the and or or keywords, like (color) and (min-width: 600px), rather than being separated with semicolons.
>
> [2.5. Combining Media Features](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mq-features)
>
> "Media conditions can be grouped by wrapping them in parentheses () which can then be nested within a condition the same as a single media query."
>
> It is invalid to mix and and or and not at the same “level” of a media query. For example, (color) and (pointer) or (hover) is illegal, as it’s unclear what was meant. Instead, parentheses can be used to group things using a particular joining keyword, yielding either (color) and ((pointer) or (hover)) or ((color) and (pointer)) or (hover). These two have very different meanings: if only (hover) is true, the first one evaluates to false but the second evaluates to true.

that some set of parentheses would work, but I can't find one. This must be due to the difference between "Media Queries" and "Media Features." The spec language seems a little unclear at places to me, e.g. the reference to "semicolons" above.